# Como o fazer pra que o Firebsae realtime NÃO carregue os dados anteriores depois de fazer um logout da conta?

Tags: java, android, firebase-database

A principio de conversa, eu sou muito novo em desenvolvimento Java android, no entanto tenho um problema com o firebase realtime em meu aplicativo. Eu ativei o .setPersistenceEnabled(true); para que funcione offline, o meu app também tem autenticação com google e firebaseAuth. Quando faço logout da conta atual no app, e logo após faço login com outra conta, o firebase carrega os dados armazenados em cache da conta anterior(como valores, dados de clientes etc..). É necessário que eu fexe o app totalmente e abri-lo novamente para que ele obtenhas os dados da conta nova. Como faço para que isso não aconteça?

// Classe que eu ativo a persistência em cache

```
public class Rdy extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    HelperClass.getDatabase();

    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    Picasso built = builder.build();
    built.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
    built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
}

public static class HelperClass {
    private static FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    public static FirebaseDatabase getDatabase() {
        if (firebaseDatabase == null) {
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
            DatabaseReference.goOnline();
        }
        return firebaseDatabase;
    }
}
```

}

// Classe String do firebase

```
 public class RdyStrings {
private static Context context;
public static FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
public static FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

public static DatabaseReference loadInicio = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid());
public static DatabaseReference savarPerfil = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()).child("perfil");


public RdyStrings(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}
```

}

// MinActivity - Aqui eu faço logout e sincronização

```
private void logout() {

    AlertDialog.Builder o = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    o.setTitle("Sair da conta")
            .setMessage("Quer sair da sua conta agora " + getDefaults("nome", context) +
                    "?")
            .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    databaseReference.keepSynced(false);
                    auth.signOut();
                    GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build()).signOut().addOnCompleteListener(context, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RdySplash.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finishAffinity();
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.no), null)
            .create()
            .show();

}

private void sync() {
    RdyStrings.salvarEstoqueRef.keepSynced(true);
    RdyStrings.salvarPreVendaRef.keepSynced(true);
    RdyStrings.clientes.keepSynced(true);
    RdyStrings.vendas.keepSynced(true);
    RdyStrings.loadInicio.keepSynced(true);
    RdyStrings.savarPerfil.keepSynced(true);
    RdyStrings.caixa.keepSynced(true);
    RdyStrings.caixaValores.keepSynced(true);
}
```

Comment: Poderia postar somente o código, nesse caso é ruim ter imagens ...

Comment: Obrigado, eu editei agora. Por favor me ajude.